# cordova app: javascript sqlite many to many relationship

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I have a Cordova project that uses SQLite to store locally some data of user. I want to create a many to many relationship, but I'm not sure how to do it.

I've read in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935620/sqlite-many-to-many-relationship) that you need to enable many to many relationships... but is that necessary in Cordova project? If so, how do I do it?

Just to be sure, how could I ask to DB, once done this if user in table U has product from table P? Is different somehow to queries in 1-1 relations?

As you can see I'm not used to working with DB, so please, asume I'm noob.